# How to use lpsolve from python in Windows 64bit

Tags: python, windows, lpsolve

I tried couple of ways to do it but I am finally not able to find the exact way to use lpsolve in python.
I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072457/installing-lpsolve-in-python27) but somehow I could not get lp_solve55.pyd. 
Currently I have the lp_solve55.dll, how should I go further from there?

Answer (score 2):

You should install the `lpsolve` package, found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lp_solve) (pick the `amd64` version if you have a 64 bit python installation), as said in the linked post. After that, you will find that the `lpsolve` module has been installed in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lpsolve`. You can then use `lpsolve` in Python by using the `import lpsolve` command.

Comment: I tried it, but when I try to install it, somehow it cannot find python installed in my system. The setup does not allow me to enter the python path also. Error is: Python version 2.7 required, which was not found in registry.

Comment: What version of python are you working with? `lpsolve` for 64-bit is only available for Python 2.6 and Python 2.7 (to my knowledge). I would suggest installing Python 2.7 64 bit.